# Blob shadow in Unity 2D

Tags: unity-game-engine, 2d, shadow

What is the best approach for blob shadows in 2D? Consider the example below:

[image]

- **A**: character is fully attached to the ground. Full complete shadow rounded on both sides;
- **B**: character is partially on the ground. Shadow is normal (rounded) on the left, and cut in the middle;
- **C**: character stays on bumpy ground. Part of the shadow is softer than the other.

To summarize: it cannot be a simple picture (uneven sides, soft/hard parts). It cannot be 3+ images: hard to implement and still looks poor on bumpy grounds. So, raycasting + image doesn't seem to be an option at all. But it should be some sort of casting to determine the distance. But what should draw the shadow? A shader? What is the best approach to take here?

Comment: Why not just use unity’s new 2d lighting.

Comment: I looked in URP and its 2d lighting. I also looked through a bunch of resources. Currently, URP 8.1 in 2020 Unity (as well as URP 7.1) aren't ready for mobile devices as far as I can tell. Performance is degrading a lot by simple static 2d lights. Moreover, shadow 2D casting is poor or doesn't exist. Read what developers themselves say about the URP status https://forum.unity.com/threads/2d-renderer-in-universal-render-pipeline-in-2019-3.829851/. I will try to roll back to the default lighting system and it might resolve my issues.

Comment: However, if the default system (or updated URP) will provide something that will help achieve this effect, it doesn't discard my question. Dynamic shadows/lighting cost way more than dummy blob shadows.